# Anybody knows why the returned of getNativeFreeHeapSize() is different from memFree info using adb shell cat /proc/meminfo

Tags: android

I thought both should return free memory size

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with Bitmap pixel data being allocated inside Native heap, although it is counted towards Dalvik heap.(pre honeycomb)

I recommend checking this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: Thanks, I have looking for some info about android memory management for a long time. Thanks for the info.